# What is this SO8 part with all legs on one side connected together?

Tags: identification

I believe this to be a voltage regulator of some kind (it's failed, and is resulting in a dead short straight through). However neither I nor Google Image Search is having any luck identifying the manufacturer mark. Does this look at all familiar to anyone?

(If anyone knows what the component is, that'd be even more awesome, but at least with the manufacturer I can look it up in their catalogue. Google doesn't know what a EDJ3207 is either, by the way.)

[image]

Comment: Most parts will have both a part number and a date code marking. While formats vary, the most common date-codes include the week within the year and the last two digits of the year, usually written as wwyy. The date code is most commonly below or after the part number. With this information in mind, the markings on that chip can separated into the "B45P03" most likely being the part number and the "EDJ3207" containing a date-code indicating that it was manufactured in the 32nd week of 2007. That this interpretation is correct can be verified in the datasheet which you have already obtained.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While I was writing up the post someone looked over my metaphorical shoulder and said 'oh, yes, that's an Excelliance P-channel MOSFET, probably the EMB45P03' and handed me the datasheet. Sigh.

https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1111730/ExcellianceMOS/EMB45P03A/1

Comment: It looks good except the data sheet shows only 4 pins.

Comment: The copy they gave me was privately shared and I can't attach it --- I thought I'd found a third-party copy of the same one, but it seems I picked the wrong package.

Comment: You can (and should) except your answer as correct or this question will keep recirculating via Community.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yes, in two days.

Answer (score 11):

Excelliance [EMB45P03G](http://www.excelliancemos.com/download_prod_s.php?ds=229&file=2) is the correct part number:

[image]

A 30V 5A logic-level P-channel MOSFET.

Comment: With this answer, you might really want to explain how you found it so later readers can piggy back on your knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kaiser I'm afraid I don't have a magic formula, I used manufacturer and the partial part number the OP had and found the actual manufacturer's website and eventually located the datasheet. Maybe OP wants to to just edit the info into his answer and let that be the whole thing?

Comment: @kaiser It's the top search result for 'b45p03' for me, so not that hard to find. Google _is_ magic!

Comment: @kaiser Google-fu involves training your personal google-instance over many years. Such training cannot be conveyed in a mere slip of a comment.

Comment: I wonder why the OP didn't find the part if it was _that_ obvious and search result number one for that device name...